# PrimeNg: Breakpoint property is not utilized and deprecated, use breakpoints or CSS media queries instead

Tags: angular, primeng

After upgrade Angular version from 7 to 11 for PrimeNg component below I have communicate:

> Breakpoint property is not utilized and deprecated, use breakpoints or CSS media queries instead.

```
<p-dialog #dialogElement [header]=header [(visible)]="visible" [resizable]="false"
[style]="style" [breakpoint]="breakpoint" (onHide)="onHide($event)" [contentStyle]="contentStyle"
[blockScroll]="true" [modal]="true" appendTo="body">
<div [ngStyle]="{'min-height':minHeight, 'height': height}">
    <ng-content select="[mp-selector-window-content]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like:

```
<p-dialog [breakpoints]="{'1920px': '70vw', '960px': '80vw', '640px': '100vw'}" </p-dialog>
```